# Transform a list of set to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

I have a list of tuples like this :

```
l=[(5, 8),(5, 9),(5, 22),(5, 6),(1, 5),(4, 5),(3, 5),(2, 5),(8, 22),(9, 22)]
```

I want to generate a dictionary with for each value; I put the values appearing with it for example for 8 I will have [5,22].

This should be the end result :

```
{1: [5],
 2: [5],
 3: [5],
 4: [5],
 5: [8, 9, 22, 6, 1, 4, 3, 2],
 6: [5],
 8: [5, 22],
 9: [5, 22],
 22: [5, 8, 9]}
```

I'm doing this and it is correctly working, but I feel it not optimized and "hard coded" is there a better version for it

```
dic={}
for n in set([item  for sublist in l for item in sublist]):
        ll=[]
        for item in  [sublist for sublist in l]:
            if n in item :
                ll.append(item[list({0,1}-{item.index(n)})[0]])
        dic[n]=ll
```

Comment: Maybe try codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: thank you , yes next time i will ask there , i didn't know about it , sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [collections.defaultdict()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import pprint
from collections import defaultdict
l=[(5, 8),(5, 9),(5, 22),(5, 6),(1, 5),(4, 5),(3, 5),(2, 5),(8, 22),(9, 22)]

d = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in l:
    d[key].append(value)
    d[value].append(key)

pprint.pprint(d)
```

Out:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {1: [5],
             2: [5],
             3: [5],
             4: [5],
             5: [8, 9, 22, 6, 1, 4, 3, 2],
             6: [5],
             8: [5, 22],
             9: [5, 22],
             22: [5, 8, 9]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would have done it, it seems much clearer than your actual code:

```py
l=[(5, 8),(5, 9),(5, 22),(5, 6),(1, 5),(4, 5),(3, 5),(2, 5),(8, 22),(9, 22)]

result = {}
for (i, v) in l:
    if i in result:
        result[i].append(v)
    else:
        result[i] = [v]
    if v in result:
        result[v].append(i)
    else:
        result[v] = [i]

print(result) # {5: [8, 9, 22, 6, 1, 4, 3, 2], 8: [5, 22], 9: [5, 22], 22: [5, 8, 9], 6: [5], 1: [5], 4: [5], 3: [5], 2: [5]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
l = [(5, 8),(5, 9),(5, 22),(5, 6),(1, 5),(4, 5),(3, 5),(2, 5),(8, 22),(9, 22)]
d = {}

for i, j in l:
    d.setdefault(i, []).append(j)
    d.setdefault(j, []).append(i)

d
```

```
{5: [8, 9, 22, 6, 1, 4, 3, 2],
 8: [5, 22],
 9: [5, 22],
 22: [5, 8, 9],
 6: [5],
 1: [5],
 4: [5],
 3: [5],
 2: [5]}
```